# CRUD of Room in Java android, how to return the count of deleted rows from Dao and AsyncTask in Ripository through viewmodel back to CatalogActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-room, delete-row, android-viewmodel

I am trying to develop this small app to do CRUD operations using `Room`, `Repository`, `LiveData`, and `ViewModel` and `Listview`, if you want to see development of the app or commit line of Java, here in this [my github repository](https://github.com/moamarubuntu/TryOfPetsWithRoom)

The original app which is called Pets at [original repository of Pets](https://github.com/udacity/ud845-Pets) is developed by using `ContentProvider` and `ContentResolver` in the subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` in Android with Java

---

the question is

Small App of android in Java to do CRUD operations by `Room`, `Repository`, `LiveData`, and `ViewModel` and `Listview`, how to return the count of deleted rows from `Dao` and `AsyncTask` in Repository through `ViewModel` back to `CatalogActivity`?

This is what in `PetDao.java`

```
@Query("DELETE FROM pets")
int deleteAllPets();
```

This is what in `PetRepository.java`

```java
// this class is inside repository
    private static class DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {
        private PetDao petDaoOfDeleteAllAsyncTask;

        DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask(PetDao petDao)
        {
            this.petDaoOfDeleteAllAsyncTask = petDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            int countOfDeletedRows = this.petDaoOfDeleteAllAsyncTask.deleteAllPets();
            return countOfDeletedRows;
        }

        /**
         * <p>Runs on the UI thread after {@link #doInBackground}. The
         * specified result is the value returned by {@link #doInBackground}.</p>
         *
         * <p>This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.</p>
         *
         * @param integer The result of the operation computed by {@link #doInBackground}.
         * @see #onPreExecute
         * @see #doInBackground
         * @see #onCancelled(Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            //super.onPostExecute(integer);
            // TODO: how to return this integer
        }
    }

    // this function is inside repository
    public void deleteAllPets()
    {
        new DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask(this.petDao).execute();
    }
```

This is what in `PetViewModel.java`

```java
public void deleteAllPets()
{
    this.petRepository.deleteAllPets();
}
```

This is what in `CatalogActivity.java`

```java
    private void deleteAllPets() {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        //
        Log.v(this.LOG_TAG, "rows deleted from pet database count is: ");

        this.petViewModel.deleteAllPets();
        // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the delete was successful.
        if (0 == 0) {
            // If no rows were deleted, then there was an error with the delete.
            Toast.makeText(this, super.getString(R.string.catalog_delete_all_pets_failed) +
                    " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, the delete was successful and we can display a toast.
            Toast.makeText(this, super.getString(R.string.catalog_delete_all_pets_successful) +
                    " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Close the activity
        //super.finish();

    }
```

I am also expecting an answer from @EpicPandaForce

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what in PetDao.java

```
@Query("DELETE FROM pets")
int deleteAllPets();
```

In your `PetRepository.java`

```
private static class DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {
        private PetDao petDaoOfDeleteAllAsyncTask;
        public MutableLiveData<Integer> resultLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

        DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask(PetDao petDao)
        {
            this.petDaoOfDeleteAllAsyncTask = petDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            int countOfDeletedRows = this.petDaoOfDeleteAllAsyncTask.deleteAllPets();
            return countOfDeletedRows;
        }

        /**
         * <p>Runs on the UI thread after {@link #doInBackground}. The
         * specified result is the value returned by {@link #doInBackground}.</p>
         *
         * <p>This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.</p>
         *
         * @param integer The result of the operation computed by {@link #doInBackground}.
         * @see #onPreExecute
         * @see #doInBackground
         * @see #onCancelled(Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            //super.onPostExecute(integer);
            // TODO: how to return this integer
            resultLiveData.postValue(integer);
        }
    }

    // this function is inside repository
    public LiveData<Integer> deleteAllPets()
    {
        DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask task = new DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask(this.petDao);
        task.execute();
        // I edited here
        return task.resultLiveData;
    }
```

In `PetViewModel.java`

```
public LiveData<Integer> deleteAllPets() {
    return this.petRepository.deleteAllPets();
}
```

In `CatalogActivity.java`

```
//
    private void deleteAllPets() {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        //
        Log.v(this.LOG_TAG, "rows deleted from pet database count is: ");

        this.petViewModel.deleteAllPets().observe(this,new Observer<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(final Integer result) {
                // here you will get result
                if (result == 0) {
                    // If no rows were deleted, then there was an error with the delete.
                    Toast.makeText(this, super.getString(R.string.catalog_delete_all_pets_failed) +
                    " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, the delete was successful and we can display a toast.
                    Toast.makeText(this, super.getString(R.string.catalog_delete_all_pets_successful) +
                    " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
               // Close the activity
               //super.finish();
            }
        });
        // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the delete was successful.
    }
```

Comment: this is how making the toast will be `Toast.makeText(this, super.getString(R.string.catalog_delete_all_pets_failed) +
                            " " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`  but in `CatalogActivity.java` this gives me an error of `error: cannot find symbol method getString(int)`

Comment: Just don't use `super` to call `getString`. use `this` to call: `this.getString()` or only `getString`.

Comment: only removing super is not working. What I did is I declared a member variable `private Context context;` then in `onCreate ` I initialized `context`  `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ..... this.context= this.getApplicationContext(); .... }`   then in the `Toast` I wrote `context` insteade of `this`  i.e. `Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.catalog_delete_all_pets_failed) +
                            " " + countOfDeletedPetsInteger, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` and that worked.

Comment: hello @Birju Vachhani , I noticed something in your answer in `PetRepository.java` how can the function `public LiveData<Integer> deleteAllPets()` access or return a field of the inner class `private static class DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>` because the function  `public LiveData<Integer> deleteAllPets()` is a member function in the outer class `PetRepository.java` and `public MutableLiveData<Integer> resultLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
` is a field or member variable in the inner class?

Comment: hello @birju-vachhani did you see my notice?

Comment: I have another question, is `static` needed in `private static class DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>` in `PetRipository.java`?

Comment: @moamarubuntu It can because the `LiveData<Integer>` is accessed using the instance of `DeleteAllPetsAsyncTask`.

Comment: @moamarubuntu I think `static` is not needed in your case.

Comment: hello @birju-vachhani then maybe you need to change something in your answer in `PetRipository.java`!